# Tracking down "missing parameter type for expanded function"

Tags: scala

Im stuck with with code, whenever I try to run it I get the error:

```
Error:(37, 66) missing parameter type for expanded function
The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: com.bfg.domain.model.RunnerSnap
  def syncPrices(pair: (RunnerSnap, RunnerChange)): RunnerSnap = {
```

However the error message is not enogh for me to know what I need to change to get this working.

```
  def syncPrices(pair: (RunnerSnap, RunnerChange)): RunnerSnap = {
    case (cache: RunnerSnap, delta: RunnerChange) =>
      val newHc = if (delta.hc.isEmpty) cache.runnerId.handicap else delta.hc
      val id = RunnerId(delta.id, newHc)
      val prices = MarketRunnerPrices(
        atl = syncPriceVolume(cache.prices.atl, delta.atl),
        atb = syncPriceVolume(cache.prices.atb, delta.atb),
        trd = syncPriceVolume(cache.prices.trd, delta.trd),
        spb = syncPriceVolume(cache.prices.spb, delta.spb),
        spl = syncPriceVolume(cache.prices.spl, delta.spl),

        batb = syncLevelPriceVolume(cache.prices.batb, delta.batb),
        batl = syncLevelPriceVolume(cache.prices.batl, delta.batl),
        bdatb = syncLevelPriceVolume(cache.prices.bdatb, delta.bdatb),
        bdatl = syncLevelPriceVolume(cache.prices.bdatl, delta.bdatl),

        spn = if (delta.spn.isEmpty) cache.prices.spn else delta.spn,
        spf = if (delta.hc.isEmpty) cache.prices.spf else delta.spf,
        ltp = if (delta.hc.isEmpty) cache.prices.ltp else delta.ltp,
        tv = if (delta.hc.isEmpty) cache.prices.tv else delta.tv
      )
      RunnerSnap(id, prices)
  }
```

> My question is: Why am I getting this error and what do I need to
>   change in my code to get it working as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `pair` `match`:

```
def syncPrices(pair: (RunnerSnap, RunnerChange)): RunnerSnap = pair match {
  case (cache: RunnerSnap, delta: RunnerChange) =>
    ...
}
```